# How to select all elements with CSS?

Tags: html, css, bulma

I have this html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=".\bulma\css\bulma.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body style="background:#1C1D1F">
    <section class="section is-large">
  <h1 class="title">Large section</h1>
  <h2 class="subtitle">
    A simple container to divide your page into <strong>sections</strong>, like the one you're currently reading.
  </h2>
</section>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this css code:

```
@font-face {
    src: url(fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf);
    font-family: lato;
 }
 .paragraph {
    font-family: lato;
 }

 @font-face {
    src: url(fonts/AthleticOutfit.ttf);
    font-family: athletic;
 }
 .title {
    font-family: athletic;
    font-size: 100px;
 }
 
* {
   color: white;
 }
```

The fonts are actually working, meaning that my css file is found. However, my * { color: white; }  does not work. I cannot figure why... I think this might have something to do with bulma, which works too.

Any idea of how to make this * {} thing work? I expect all my text to be in white color, but it actually shows as grey...

Comment: Try adding `!important` , like `color: white !important`.

Comment: Find out who/where is setting the different color by using your browser's devtools inspect facility. Look at any element that has the wrong color and you will see all the places that tried to set it. (and try to avoid using !important if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

`color: white !important`

Option 2: add a class "something" to your `<body>` then you can utilize precedance.

```
body.something * {
    color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code works just fine. I tested it myself a couple of times and it works perfectly. Try checking for typos, maybe add a <!DOCTYPE> at the beginning just in case, make sure that nothing in the other style sheet contradicts, or if nothing works, try adding the !important tag after the style for coloring it white, like "color: white !important".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).